# Returning object in a function Laravel 4

Tags: php

I am trying to access a functions variable from another function in the same class. i am fairly new to the concept and I can get it to work in another function but when I try to create it's own function I get an `Trying to get property of non-object` I know what that means but it's confusing as to what needs to be returned in my function since it does work in my other function.

**Function getting the error**

```
public function getEditTotal($id) {

    $techs = $this->technician();

    $tech = $techs->tech;

    var_dump($tech); die;

    return View::make('report.edit', array('pageTitle' => 'Edit Report Total', 'id' => $id, 'tech' => $tech));
}`
```

**The function I am trying to call**

```
public function technician() {
    $tech = DB::table('technician')
            ->get();

    return $tech;
}
```

I had that same `$tech` variable in this function and it worked perfectly fine if I called `$this->setComplete($id)` instead.

**Returned statement in the setComplete($id) function**

```
return View::make('report.total', array('pageTitle' => 'Reporting', 'id' => $id, 'tech' => $tech, 'status' => $status));
```

I am sure it's just the way it's being returned since that variable is being returned in `setComplete($id)` in the array. I just don't know how to strictly call it in the `technician()` function.

Answer (score 1):

When you call `$techs = $this->technician();` you are setting the $techs to be whatever the value of the $tech variable in the technician function.  That is going to be the result of DB::table('technician')
            ->get();

Theoretically this should be an array of objects where each object represents one row in the technician table.

If you want to know what's going on, add a var_dump($tech) inside the your technician() function, just prior to the return $tech statement.

Since you indicate it is working as expected, you're getting an array of objects.  I'm not sure what you want to do with those, but inside the controller:

```
foreach ($techs as $tech) {
    echo $tech->somefieldInTech;
}
```

or perhaps

```
echo $techs[0]->somefieldInTech;
```

So to be clear, in your laravel template, you might want to pass the entire $techs and foreach through it in the template, although from your code it's not clear what you need to do with the data.

Comment: yes, that's exactly what I get. Most of the time I would just set the table up and foreach it in the template. What should the return be then if i am just wanting to return that entire piece? So, if I want to loop through it on other pages or functions I can. I am basically wanting exactly what the var_dump is on the return.